# Applying a function to a pandas col

Tags: python, function, numpy, pandas

I would like to map the function `GetPermittedFAR` to my `dataframe(df)` such that I could test if a value in the col zonedist1 == a certain value I could build new cols such as `df['FAR_Permitted']` etc.

I have tried various means of `map()` etc. but haven't gotten this to work. I feel this should be a pretty simple thing to do?

Ideally, I would use a simple list comprehension / lambda as I have many of these test conditional values resulting in col data to create.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def GetPermittedFAR():
    if df['zonedist1'] == 'R7-3':
        df['FAR_Permitted'] = 0.5
        df['Building Height Max'] = 35

    if df['zonedist1'] == 'R3-2':
       df['FAR_Permitted'] = 0.5
       df['Building Height Max'] = 35

    if df['zonedist1'] == 'R1-1':
       df['FAR_Permitted'] = 0.7
       df['Building Height Max'] = 100
    #etc...if statement for each unique value in 'zonedist'

df = pd.DataFrame({'zonedist1':['R7-3', 'R3-2', 'R1-1', 
                               'R1-2', 'R2', 'R2A', 'R2X',
                               'R1-1','R7-3','R3-2','R7-3',
                               'R3-2', 'R1-1', 'R1-2'
                                ]}

df = df.apply(lambda x: GetPermittedFAR(), axis=1)
```

Comment: What is the exact output you need? Can you post it?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Interesting perhaps I am overthinking this. I tried to generalize the problem and maybe left out some important criteria. I am going to edit the above code. 'zonedist' has repeating values, i need to assert 2 new columns to my data based on whatever value is in zonedist,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `pd.merge()`?

Let `df` be your dataframe

```
In [612]: df
Out[612]:
  zonedist1
0      R7-3
1      R3-2
2      R1-1
3      R1-2
4        R2
5       R2A
6       R2X
```

`merge` be another dataframe with conditions

```
In [613]: merge
Out[613]:
  zonedist1  FAR_Permitted  Building Height Max
0      R7-3            0.5                   35
1      R3-2            0.5                   35
```

Then, merge `df` with `merge` on 'left'

```
In [614]: df.merge(merge, how='left')
Out[614]:
  zonedist1  FAR_Permitted  Building Height Max
0      R7-3            0.5                   35
1      R3-2            0.5                   35
2      R1-1            NaN                  NaN
3      R1-2            NaN                  NaN
4        R2            NaN                  NaN
5       R2A            NaN                  NaN
6       R2X            NaN                  NaN
```

Later you can replace `NaN` values.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this : "merge be another dataframe with conditions". are you saying the col FAR_permitted can actually contain a conditional? Can you give an example syntax for this; I am not familiar but sounds amazing!